# Controlling the terminal while in the middle of a pipe

Tags: shell, io-redirection, tty

Say I have 3 commands linked through pipes:

```
A | B | C
```

I would like B to output error messages to stderr and some progress to the terminal. If stderr is the same as the terminal, then that is easy: Simply send the progress information to stderr. But what if stderr is redirected?

```
A | B 2>/tmp/file | C
```

Then I still want the progress information to go to the terminal, while error messages go to the file.

Can I now somehow identify the terminal that stderr would have ended up on had it not been redirected?

My initial idea would be to find the tty using `tty` and then opening that and writing to it. However, if I call `tty` from inside B `tty` says: `not a tty`, which I believe is because of the pipe between A and B.

I would like to do this from Perl.

Comment: Try to find the parent process's fds.

Comment: You can use a `tee` programm: **tee** - *read from standard input and write to standard output and files*

Comment: You cannot use tee. tee makes a copy of the stream. That is not the wanted behaviour.

Comment: Open `/dev/tty` and write to it.

Answer (score 1):

Linux specific:

```
echo |perl -e '$p=getppid; `echo foo > /proc/$p/fd/2`'
```

If you here redirect stderr 'foo' is still printed on the terminal:

```
echo |perl -e '$p=getppid; `echo foo > /proc/$p/fd/2`' 2>/dev/null
```